# Multithread How to know when all task are finished (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading

Here is my question: What is the best and smarter way to know "When a group of certain tasks finishes to be able to start some other tasks depending on the group that just finished"

For example I have this tree, So When A finishes, I can can start H and B etc...
But on my little tree bellow you also need to know that each letters to be considered finished has to do certain tasks (also in parallel)

```
           A
         /   \
       H       B
     /        /  \
   C         F     D
```

So a full example would be:

```
- Starting A
     - Starting instance 1 of A
     - Starting instance 2 of A
     - Starting instance 3 of A
     - Instance 1 of A Finished
     - Instance 2 of A Finished
     - Instance 3 of A Finished

- Starting H
- Starting B
     - Starting instance 1 of H
     - Starting instance 2 of H
     - Starting instance 1 of B
     - Starting instance 3 of H
     - B has completed all its tasks
- Starting F
     - Starting instance 4 of H
     - H has completed all its tasks
- Starting C
etc...
```

So to resume my question: Which would be the best structure to wait that all the tasks of A for example finishes to be able to start B  and H ?

For the moment This is what I'm doing based on the lib thread pool of a certain christian, using callbacks
http://www.chrisarndt.de/projects/threadpool/

For each letters I have the number of task to be completed so I have create a dict like that

```
instances_count = {"A":[0,5],"B":[0,2],"H":[0,3],"C":[0,0],"D":[0,1]}
```

The a make my first request like that

```
requests = threadpool.makeRequests(do_something, ["A"],print_result)
```

print_result will be called when do_something finishes

```
def do_something(data):

    Here I just retrieve what the Tasks of A and make an other request to parallelize them

   command_requests = threadpool.makeRequests(execute_command, argument_list,instance_finished)


def execute_command(data):
   Here I Do what the task has to do and when it is done i return the datas
   return data

def instance_finished():
    And here what I do is that I will use that instance_count to add +1 when A task reletated to a Letter finishes...

   Global.Lock()
   instances_count[Letter][0] = instances_count[Letter][0] + 1
   Global.unLock()
```

and I check if instances_count[Letter][0] == instances_count[Letter][1] that means that all the tasks of A are finished and I can "Start" the letters B and H

So Can somebody tell me if this a Good solution? If no How can I improve that ?

Thank you !

Comment: ["Other threads can call a thread’s join() method. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called is terminated."](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you to use the [Mutltiprocessing Module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)

Set up a worker pool and add tasks with `apply_async` or alike mapping functions.

`apply_async` will give you back an `AsyncResult` object. An `AsyncResult` object have the following methods.

> wait([timeout])
>
> > Wait until the result is available or until timeout
> >     seconds pass.
>
> ready()
>
> > Return whether the call has completed.

Is is all in the link above.. Best of luck.

Comment: Note, that you also can use callback functions with apply_async. :)

Comment: Ok this is what was in the back of my head, something that tells me when a 'single' task has finished and not the entire pool like does the threadpool lib that im using. I Will try to play a bit with multiproc lib and see if i can get a nice solution